# Rendering issue while centering Font Awesome icon

Tags: dart, flutter, widget, icons

I don't understand why this FAB doesn't center it's child. I've tried different things but cannot make it to center perfectly. Because adding for example padding only bottom to the icon could make it center on a Device but maybe not for all. 
this is my code

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      highlightColor: Colors.red, splashColor: Colors.red),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 100,
        shape: new CircleBorder(
            side: new BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black, width: 5.0)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Icon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.chevronUp,
          size: 80,
        )),
  ),
),
```

and this is the not centered FAB with it's icon child.

[image]

does it seems only to me that the icon isn't centered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same code with Icons.person

[image: Icons.person]

same code with Text widget

[image: Text Widget]

Same code with chevronCircleUp

[image: chevronCircleUp]

I've used `Show Debug Paint` by the way. And I've used chevronCircleUp, just to see clearly the area of widget. I think you are right, it's not centered enough, however, this examples made me think that the problem is related to FontAwesome icons.

There are also this issues

[Font Icon Render Box not large enough for some characters](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24054)

[Rectangular icons are centered incorrectly](https://github.com/brianegan/font_awesome_flutter/issues/23)

So I've applied the workaround on the first issue, here is the code. It must be good enough now.

```
Theme.of(context)
              .copyWith(highlightColor: Colors.red, splashColor: Colors.red),
          child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                elevation: 100,
                shape: new CircleBorder(
                    side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 5.0)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                    String.fromCharCode(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.chevronUp.codePoint),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 72.0,
                        fontFamily: FontAwesomeIcons.chevronUp.fontFamily,
                        package: FontAwesomeIcons.chevronUp.fontPackage)),
              )),
        ),
```

[image: chevronUp]

**Edit after 3 years:**

Issue still exists with Material icon (Icons.ios_share) on Flutter 2.10.0

[image: issue]

Comment: Well this is interesting then. I think that we should make this relevant to someone. At least I am not crazy. Didn't know the use of that Show Debug Paint. Thanks.

Comment: Please mark as solved if the code that I just provided works for you @FlorisMarpepa

Comment: Well not really because if I make the fontsize in this case a lot bigger it doesn't center again. however the Theme has to have a data in wich i put your code. Didn't work just putted there this way.