# How to use same size for Material Icons and Font Awesome Icons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using Material Icons and Font Awesome Icons in my app, trying to make them same size. I don't know if Material Icons have padding, but they don't seem to have same size to me.

Relevant issues and SO posts about it:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54933040/9779791
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24054
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34958
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/issues/23

  ```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: blueColor,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: 15,
          height: 15,
          child: Icon(
            iconData,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```

[image: screenshot]

I'm using `Icons.directions_run` and `FontAwesomeIcons.mountain` with my custom widget(I needed a circular background for them, open for suggestions), but I couldn't make them same size.

Here's how they look in Debug Painting:

[image: screenshot with debug painting on]

Also I've removed `size` from `Icon` and use another `Container` to resize icon. Here's the code for that:

```
class ChallengeDetailIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChallengeDetailIcon({@required this.iconData});

  final IconData iconData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 24,
      height: 24,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: blueColor,
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: 15,
        height: 15,
        child: Icon(
          iconData,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But it didn't work.

[image: screenshot for second code snippet]

**EDIT:** Tried `FaIcon`

Code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 24,
      height: 24,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: blueColor,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: FaIcon(
          iconData,
          size: 12,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: After FaIcon]

With size 15
[image: FaIcon with size 15]

Answer (score 1):

notice about this: [...] Why aren't the icons aligned properly or why are the icons being cut off? #
Please use the FaIcon widget provided by the library instead of the Icon widget provided by Flutter. The Icon widget assumes all icons are square, but many Font Awesome Icons are not. [...]

https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

try to use `FaIcon` instead of `Icon` for fontawesome

import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      // Use the FaIcon Widget + FontAwesomeIcons class for the IconData
      icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.gamepad), 
      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
     );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

A second solution for this could be controlling it with iconTheme:

```
theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 36.0, color: Colors.black87),
...
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconTheme-class.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was an issue and solution about it. I tried this and edited my question,

Comment: Yes, no luck with IconTheme either